# echo $PATH does not reflect my bash_profile after python modification

Tags: homebrew, python-3.5, bash

I recently checked my .bash_profile under`/Users/tianhao` which have been modified to following:

> ```
> # Setting PATH for Python 3.5
> # The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
> # PATH="${PATH}"
> # export PATH
> # export PATH=’/usr/local/bin:/"
> ```
>
> /Users/tianhaoxu/.bash_profile (END)

this does not match my  `echo $PATH` command result:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

I want to know why it doesn't match and all the lines are starting with #. I installed python3.5 by homebrew, which does not have any issues when I run `brew doctor`

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: The # is a comment so that might be the problem. Otherwise you might need the source .bash_profile to get it to update.

Comment: Just as Rober said , # is a comment, it can't be set path, if you want to set, you should remove #  in the front.

Answer (score 1):

Just as Rober said , # is a comment, it can't set path, if you want to set, you should remove #  in the front. I think

```
 "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin"
```

is set by the system default. Give you an example, if you want to add "home/tianhao/important/document" into you path, you can set(different pathes should be separated by  colon)

```
PATH=$PATH:home/tianhao/important/document
export PATH
```